# PHP.ini Mysql issues

Tags: mysql, windows, configuration, php

I've spent a lot of time trying to fix this issues. I keep getting a `Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect()` error so I did some net trawling and others are having the same problem but manage to fix it by including 'extension=' and un-commenting 'extension=php_mysql.dll' but as you can see doing both of those things still don't work. What have a missed?

MY PHP ini (I am on Windows 7) (Trimmed!)

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Paths and Directories ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

; UNIX: "/path1:/path2"
;include_path = ".:/php/includes"
;
; Windows: "\path1;\path2"
include_path = ".;c:\php\includes"
;
; PHP's default setting for include_path is ".;/path/to/php/pear"
; http://php.net/include-path

; The root of the PHP pages, used only if nonempty.
; if PHP was not compiled with FORCE_REDIRECT, you SHOULD set doc_root
; if you are running php as a CGI under any web server (other than IIS)
; see documentation for security issues.  The alternate is to use the
; cgi.force_redirect configuration below
; http://php.net/doc-root
doc_root =

; The directory under which PHP opens the script using /~username used only
; if nonempty.
; http://php.net/user-dir
user_dir =

; Directory in which the loadable extensions (modules) reside.
; http://php.net/extension-dir
; extension_dir = "./"
; On windows:
; extension_dir = "ext"

; Whether or not to enable the dl() function.  The dl() function does NOT work
; properly in multithreaded servers, such as IIS or Zeus, and is automatically
; disabled on them.
; http://php.net/enable-dl
enable_dl = Off

; cgi.force_redirect is necessary to provide security running PHP as a CGI under
; most web servers.  Left undefined, PHP turns this on by default.  You can
; turn it off here AT YOUR OWN RISK
; **You CAN safely turn this off for IIS, in fact, you MUST.**
; http://php.net/cgi.force-redirect
;cgi.force_redirect = 1

; if cgi.nph is enabled it will force cgi to always sent Status: 200 with
; every request. PHP's default behavior is to disable this feature.
;cgi.nph = 1

; if cgi.force_redirect is turned on, and you are not running under Apache or Netscape
; (iPlanet) web servers, you MAY need to set an environment variable name that PHP
; will look for to know it is OK to continue execution.  Setting this variable MAY
; cause security issues, KNOW WHAT YOU ARE DOING FIRST.
; http://php.net/cgi.redirect-status-env
;cgi.redirect_status_env = 

; cgi.fix_pathinfo provides *real* PATH_INFO/PATH_TRANSLATED support for CGI.  PHP's
; previous behaviour was to set PATH_TRANSLATED to SCRIPT_FILENAME, and to not grok
; what PATH_INFO is.  For more information on PATH_INFO, see the cgi specs.  Setting
; this to 1 will cause PHP CGI to fix its paths to conform to the spec.  A setting
; of zero causes PHP to behave as before.  Default is 1.  You should fix your scripts
; to use SCRIPT_FILENAME rather than PATH_TRANSLATED.
; http://php.net/cgi.fix-pathinfo
;cgi.fix_pathinfo=1

; FastCGI under IIS (on WINNT based OS) supports the ability to impersonate
; security tokens of the calling client.  This allows IIS to define the
; security context that the request runs under.  mod_fastcgi under Apache
; does not currently support this feature (03/17/2002)
; Set to 1 if running under IIS.  Default is zero.
; http://php.net/fastcgi.impersonate
;fastcgi.impersonate = 1

; Disable logging through FastCGI connection. PHP's default behavior is to enable
; this feature.
;fastcgi.logging = 0

; cgi.rfc2616_headers configuration option tells PHP what type of headers to
; use when sending HTTP response code. If it's set 0 PHP sends Status: header that
; is supported by Apache. When this option is set to 1 PHP will send
; RFC2616 compliant header.
; Default is zero.
; http://php.net/cgi.rfc2616-headers
;cgi.rfc2616_headers = 0

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; File Uploads ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

; Whether to allow HTTP file uploads.
; http://php.net/file-uploads
file_uploads = On

; Temporary directory for HTTP uploaded files (will use system default if not
; specified).
; http://php.net/upload-tmp-dir
;upload_tmp_dir =

; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
; http://php.net/upload-max-filesize
upload_max_filesize = 2M

; Maximum number of files that can be uploaded via a single request
max_file_uploads = 20

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Fopen wrappers ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

; Whether to allow the treatment of URLs (like http:// or ftp://) as files.
; http://php.net/allow-url-fopen
allow_url_fopen = On

; Whether to allow include/require to open URLs (like http:// or ftp://) as files.
; http://php.net/allow-url-include
allow_url_include = Off

; Define the anonymous ftp password (your email address). PHP's default setting
; for this is empty.
; http://php.net/from
;from="john@doe.com"

; Define the User-Agent string. PHP's default setting for this is empty.
; http://php.net/user-agent
;user_agent="PHP"

; Default timeout for socket based streams (seconds)
; http://php.net/default-socket-timeout
default_socket_timeout = 60

; If your scripts have to deal with files from Macintosh systems,
; or you are running on a Mac and need to deal with files from
; unix or win32 systems, setting this flag will cause PHP to
; automatically detect the EOL character in those files so that
; fgets() and file() will work regardless of the source of the file.
; http://php.net/auto-detect-line-endings
;auto_detect_line_endings = Off

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Dynamic Extensions ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

; If you wish to have an extension loaded automatically, use the following
; syntax:
;
;   extension=modulename.extension
;
; For example, on Windows:
;
   extension=c:\PHP\ext\msql.dll
;
; ... or under UNIX:
;
;   extension=c:\PHP\ext\msql.so
;
; ... or with a path:
;
;   extension=/path/to/extension/msql.so
;
; If you only provide the name of the extension, PHP will look for it in its
; default extension directory.
;
; Windows Extensions
; Note that ODBC support is built in, so no dll is needed for it.
; Note that many DLL files are located in the extensions/ (PHP 4) ext/ (PHP 5)
; extension folders as well as the separate PECL DLL download (PHP 5).
; Be sure to appropriately set the extension_dir directive.
;
;extension=php_bz2.dll
;extension=php_curl.dll
;extension=php_fileinfo.dll
;extension=php_gd2.dll
;extension=php_gettext.dll
;extension=php_gmp.dll
;extension=php_intl.dll
;extension=php_imap.dll
;extension=php_interbase.dll
;extension=php_ldap.dll
;extension=php_mbstring.dll
;extension=php_exif.dll      ; Must be after mbstring as it depends on it
extension=php_mysql.dll
extension=php_mysqli.dll
;extension=php_oci8.dll      ; Use with Oracle 10gR2 Instant Client
;extension=php_oci8_11g.dll  ; Use with Oracle 11gR2 Instant Client
;extension=php_openssl.dll
;extension=php_pdo_firebird.dll
;extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
;extension=php_pdo_oci.dll
;extension=php_pdo_odbc.dll
;extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll
;extension=php_pdo_sqlite.dll
;extension=php_pgsql.dll
;extension=php_pspell.dll
;extension=php_shmop.dll

; The MIBS data available in the PHP distribution must be installed. 
; See http://www.php.net/manual/en/snmp.installation.php 
;extension=php_snmp.dll

;extension=php_soap.dll
;extension=php_sockets.dll
;extension=php_sqlite3.dll
;extension=php_sybase_ct.dll
;extension=php_tidy.dll
;extension=php_xmlrpc.dll
;extension=php_xsl.dll
;extension=php_zip.dll

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Module Settings ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

[CLI Server]
; Whether the CLI web server uses ANSI color coding in its terminal output.
cli_server.color = On

[Date]
; Defines the default timezone used by the date functions
; http://php.net/date.timezone
;date.timezone =

; http://php.net/date.default-latitude
;date.default_latitude = 31.7667

; http://php.net/date.default-longitude
;date.default_longitude = 35.2333

; http://php.net/date.sunrise-zenith
;date.sunrise_zenith = 90.583333

; http://php.net/date.sunset-zenith
;date.sunset_zenith = 90.583333

[filter]
; http://php.net/filter.default
;filter.default = unsafe_raw

; http://php.net/filter.default-flags
;filter.default_flags =

[iconv]
;iconv.input_encoding = ISO-8859-1
;iconv.internal_encoding = ISO-8859-1
;iconv.output_encoding = ISO-8859-1

[intl]
;intl.default_locale =
; This directive allows you to produce PHP errors when some error
; happens within intl functions. The value is the level of the error produced.
; Default is 0, which does not produce any errors.
;intl.error_level = E_WARNING

[sqlite]
; http://php.net/sqlite.assoc-case
;sqlite.assoc_case = 0

[sqlite3]
;sqlite3.extension_dir =

[Pcre]
;PCRE library backtracking limit.
; http://php.net/pcre.backtrack-limit
;pcre.backtrack_limit=100000

;PCRE library recursion limit.
;Please note that if you set this value to a high number you may consume all
;the available process stack and eventually crash PHP (due to reaching the
;stack size limit imposed by the Operating System).
; http://php.net/pcre.recursion-limit
;pcre.recursion_limit=100000

[Pdo]
; Whether to pool ODBC connections. Can be one of "strict", "relaxed" or "off"
; http://php.net/pdo-odbc.connection-pooling
;pdo_odbc.connection_pooling=strict

;pdo_odbc.db2_instance_name

[Pdo_mysql]
; If mysqlnd is used: Number of cache slots for the internal result set cache
; http://php.net/pdo_mysql.cache_size
pdo_mysql.cache_size = 2000

; Default socket name for local MySQL connects.  If empty, uses the built-in
; MySQL defaults.
; http://php.net/pdo_mysql.default-socket
pdo_mysql.default_socket=

[Phar]
; http://php.net/phar.readonly
;phar.readonly = On

; http://php.net/phar.require-hash
;phar.require_hash = On

;phar.cache_list =

[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/smtp
SMTP = localhost
; http://php.net/smtp-port
smtp_port = 25

; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/sendmail-from
;sendmail_from = me@example.com

; For Unix only.  You may supply arguments as well (default: "sendmail -t -i").
; http://php.net/sendmail-path
;sendmail_path =

; Force the addition of the specified parameters to be passed as extra parameters
; to the sendmail binary. These parameters will always replace the value of
; the 5th parameter to mail(), even in safe mode.
;mail.force_extra_parameters =

; Add X-PHP-Originating-Script: that will include uid of the script followed by the filename
mail.add_x_header = On

; The path to a log file that will log all mail() calls. Log entries include
; the full path of the script, line number, To address and headers.
;mail.log =
; Log mail to syslog (Event Log on NT, not valid in Windows 95).
;mail.log = syslog

[SQL]
; http://php.net/sql.safe-mode
sql.safe_mode = Off

[ODBC]
; http://php.net/odbc.default-db
;odbc.default_db    =  Not yet implemented

; http://php.net/odbc.default-user
;odbc.default_user  =  Not yet implemented

; http://php.net/odbc.default-pw
;odbc.default_pw    =  Not yet implemented

; Controls the ODBC cursor model.
; Default: SQL_CURSOR_STATIC (default).
;odbc.default_cursortype

; Allow or prevent persistent links.
; http://php.net/odbc.allow-persistent
odbc.allow_persistent = On

; Check that a connection is still valid before reuse.
; http://php.net/odbc.check-persistent
odbc.check_persistent = On

; Maximum number of persistent links.  -1 means no limit.
; http://php.net/odbc.max-persistent
odbc.max_persistent = -1

; Maximum number of links (persistent + non-persistent).  -1 means no limit.
; http://php.net/odbc.max-links
odbc.max_links = -1

; Handling of LONG fields.  Returns number of bytes to variables.  0 means
; passthru.
; http://php.net/odbc.defaultlrl
odbc.defaultlrl = 4096

; Handling of binary data.  0 means passthru, 1 return as is, 2 convert to char.
; See the documentation on odbc_binmode and odbc_longreadlen for an explanation
; of odbc.defaultlrl and odbc.defaultbinmode
; http://php.net/odbc.defaultbinmode
odbc.defaultbinmode = 1

;birdstep.max_links = -1

[Interbase]
; Allow or prevent persistent links.
ibase.allow_persistent = 1

; Maximum number of persistent links.  -1 means no limit.
ibase.max_persistent = -1

; Maximum number of links (persistent + non-persistent).  -1 means no limit.
ibase.max_links = -1

; Default database name for ibase_connect().
;ibase.default_db =

; Default username for ibase_connect().
;ibase.default_user =

; Default password for ibase_connect().
;ibase.default_password =

; Default charset for ibase_connect().
;ibase.default_charset =

; Default timestamp format.
ibase.timestampformat = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"

; Default date format.
ibase.dateformat = "%Y-%m-%d"

; Default time format.
ibase.timeformat = "%H:%M:%S"

[MySQL]
; Allow accessing, from PHP's perspective, local files with LOAD DATA statements
; http://php.net/mysql.allow_local_infile
mysql.allow_local_infile = On

; Allow or prevent persistent links.
; http://php.net/mysql.allow-persistent
mysql.allow_persistent = On

; If mysqlnd is used: Number of cache slots for the internal result set cache
; http://php.net/mysql.cache_size
mysql.cache_size = 2000

; Maximum number of persistent links.  -1 means no limit.
; http://php.net/mysql.max-persistent
mysql.max_persistent = -1

; Maximum number of links (persistent + non-persistent).  -1 means no limit.
; http://php.net/mysql.max-links
mysql.max_links = -1

; Default port number for mysql_connect().  If unset, mysql_connect() will use
; the $MYSQL_TCP_PORT or the mysql-tcp entry in /etc/services or the
; compile-time value defined MYSQL_PORT (in that order).  Win32 will only look
; at MYSQL_PORT.
; http://php.net/mysql.default-port
mysql.default_port =

; Default socket name for local MySQL connects.  If empty, uses the built-in
; MySQL defaults.
; http://php.net/mysql.default-socket
mysql.default_socket =

; Default host for mysql_connect() (doesn't apply in safe mode).
; http://php.net/mysql.default-host
mysql.default_host =

; Default user for mysql_connect() (doesn't apply in safe mode).
; http://php.net/mysql.default-user
mysql.default_user =

; Default password for mysql_connect() (doesn't apply in safe mode).
; Note that this is generally a *bad* idea to store passwords in this file.
; *Any* user with PHP access can run 'echo get_cfg_var("mysql.default_password")
; and reveal this password!  And of course, any users with read access to this
; file will be able to reveal the password as well.
; http://php.net/mysql.default-password
mysql.default_password =

; Maximum time (in seconds) for connect timeout. -1 means no limit
; http://php.net/mysql.connect-timeout
mysql.connect_timeout = 60

; Trace mode. When trace_mode is active (=On), warnings for table/index scans and
; SQL-Errors will be displayed.
; http://php.net/mysql.trace-mode
mysql.trace_mode = Off

[MySQLi]

; Maximum number of persistent links.  -1 means no limit.
; http://php.net/mysqli.max-persistent
mysqli.max_persistent = -1

; Allow accessing, from PHP's perspective, local files with LOAD DATA statements
; http://php.net/mysqli.allow_local_infile
;mysqli.allow_local_infile = On

; Allow or prevent persistent links.
; http://php.net/mysqli.allow-persistent
mysqli.allow_persistent = On

; Maximum number of links.  -1 means no limit.
; http://php.net/mysqli.max-links
mysqli.max_links = -1

; If mysqlnd is used: Number of cache slots for the internal result set cache
; http://php.net/mysqli.cache_size
mysqli.cache_size = 2000

; Default port number for mysqli_connect().  If unset, mysqli_connect() will use
; the $MYSQL_TCP_PORT or the mysql-tcp entry in /etc/services or the
; compile-time value defined MYSQL_PORT (in that order).  Win32 will only look
; at MYSQL_PORT.
; http://php.net/mysqli.default-port
mysqli.default_port = 3306

; Default socket name for local MySQL connects.  If empty, uses the built-in
; MySQL defaults.
; http://php.net/mysqli.default-socket
mysqli.default_socket =

; Default host for mysql_connect() (doesn't apply in safe mode).
; http://php.net/mysqli.default-host
mysqli.default_host =

; Default user for mysql_connect() (doesn't apply in safe mode).
; http://php.net/mysqli.default-user
mysqli.default_user =

; Default password for mysqli_connect() (doesn't apply in safe mode).
; Note that this is generally a *bad* idea to store passwords in this file.
; *Any* user with PHP access can run 'echo get_cfg_var("mysqli.default_pw")
; and reveal this password!  And of course, any users with read access to this
; file will be able to reveal the password as well.
; http://php.net/mysqli.default-pw
mysqli.default_pw =

; Allow or prevent reconnect
mysqli.reconnect = Off

[mysqlnd]
; Enable / Disable collection of general statistics by mysqlnd which can be
; used to tune and monitor MySQL operations.
; http://php.net/mysqlnd.collect_statistics
mysqlnd.collect_statistics = On

; Enable / Disable collection of memory usage statistics by mysqlnd which can be
; used to tune and monitor MySQL operations.
; http://php.net/mysqlnd.collect_memory_statistics
mysqlnd.collect_memory_statistics = On

; Size of a pre-allocated buffer used when sending commands to MySQL in bytes.
; http://php.net/mysqlnd.net_cmd_buffer_size
;mysqlnd.net_cmd_buffer_size = 2048

; Size of a pre-allocated buffer used for reading data sent by the server in
; bytes.
; http://php.net/mysqlnd.net_read_buffer_size
;mysqlnd.net_read_buffer_size = 32768

[OCI8]

; Connection: Enables privileged connections using external
; credentials (OCI_SYSOPER, OCI_SYSDBA)
; http://php.net/oci8.privileged-connect
;oci8.privileged_connect = Off

; Connection: The maximum number of persistent OCI8 connections per
; process. Using -1 means no limit.
; http://php.net/oci8.max-persistent
;oci8.max_persistent = -1

; Connection: The maximum number of seconds a process is allowed to
; maintain an idle persistent connection. Using -1 means idle
; persistent connections will be maintained forever.
; http://php.net/oci8.persistent-timeout
;oci8.persistent_timeout = -1

; Connection: The number of seconds that must pass before issuing a
; ping during oci_pconnect() to check the connection validity. When
; set to 0, each oci_pconnect() will cause a ping. Using -1 disables
; pings completely.
; http://php.net/oci8.ping-interval
;oci8.ping_interval = 60

; Connection: Set this to a user chosen connection class to be used
; for all pooled server requests with Oracle 11g Database Resident
; Connection Pooling (DRCP).  To use DRCP, this value should be set to
; the same string for all web servers running the same application,
; the database pool must be configured, and the connection string must
; specify to use a pooled server.
;oci8.connection_class =

; High Availability: Using On lets PHP receive Fast Application
; Notification (FAN) events generated when a database node fails. The
; database must also be configured to post FAN events.
;oci8.events = Off

; Tuning: This option enables statement caching, and specifies how
; many statements to cache. Using 0 disables statement caching.
; http://php.net/oci8.statement-cache-size
;oci8.statement_cache_size = 20

; Tuning: Enables statement prefetching and sets the default number of
; rows that will be fetched automatically after statement execution.
; http://php.net/oci8.default-prefetch
;oci8.default_prefetch = 100

; Compatibility. Using On means oci_close() will not close
; oci_connect() and oci_new_connect() connections.
; http://php.net/oci8.old-oci-close-semantics
;oci8.old_oci_close_semantics = Off

[PostgreSQL]
; Allow or prevent persistent links.
; http://php.net/pgsql.allow-persistent
pgsql.allow_persistent = On

; Detect broken persistent links always with pg_pconnect().
; Auto reset feature requires a little overheads.
; http://php.net/pgsql.auto-reset-persistent
pgsql.auto_reset_persistent = Off

; Maximum number of persistent links.  -1 means no limit.
; http://php.net/pgsql.max-persistent
pgsql.max_persistent = -1

; Maximum number of links (persistent+non persistent).  -1 means no limit.
; http://php.net/pgsql.max-links
pgsql.max_links = -1

; Ignore PostgreSQL backends Notice message or not.
; Notice message logging require a little overheads.
; http://php.net/pgsql.ignore-notice
pgsql.ignore_notice = 0

; Log PostgreSQL backends Notice message or not.
; Unless pgsql.ignore_notice=0, module cannot log notice message.
; http://php.net/pgsql.log-notice
pgsql.log_notice = 0

[Sybase-CT]
; Allow or prevent persistent links.
; http://php.net/sybct.allow-persistent
sybct.allow_persistent = On

; Maximum number of persistent links.  -1 means no limit.
; http://php.net/sybct.max-persistent
sybct.max_persistent = -1

; Maximum number of links (persistent + non-persistent).  -1 means no limit.
; http://php.net/sybct.max-links
sybct.max_links = -1

; Minimum server message severity to display.
; http://php.net/sybct.min-server-severity
sybct.min_server_severity = 10

; Minimum client message severity to display.
; http://php.net/sybct.min-client-severity
sybct.min_client_severity = 10

; Set per-context timeout
; http://php.net/sybct.timeout
;sybct.timeout=

;sybct.packet_size

; The maximum time in seconds to wait for a connection attempt to succeed before returning failure.
; Default: one minute
;sybct.login_timeout=

; The name of the host you claim to be connecting from, for display by sp_who.
; Default: none
;sybct.hostname=

; Allows you to define how often deadlocks are to be retried. -1 means "forever".
; Default: 0
;sybct.deadlock_retry_count=

[bcmath]
; Number of decimal digits for all bcmath functions.
; http://php.net/bcmath.scale
bcmath.scale = 0

[browscap]
; http://php.net/browscap
;browscap = extra/browscap.ini

[Session]
; Handler used to store/retrieve data.
; http://php.net/session.save-handler
session.save_handler = files

; Argument passed to save_handler.  In the case of files, this is the path
; where data files are stored. Note: Windows users have to change this
; variable in order to use PHP's session functions.
;
; The path can be defined as:
;
;     session.save_path = "N;/path"
;
; where N is an integer.  Instead of storing all the session files in
; /path, what this will do is use subdirectories N-levels deep, and
; store the session data in those directories.  This is useful if you
; or your OS have problems with lots of files in one directory, and is
; a more efficient layout for servers that handle lots of sessions.
;
; NOTE 1: PHP will not create this directory structure automatically.
;         You can use the script in the ext/session dir for that purpose.
; NOTE 2: See the section on garbage collection below if you choose to
;         use subdirectories for session storage
;
; The file storage module creates files using mode 600 by default.
; You can change that by using
;
;     session.save_path = "N;MODE;/path"
;
; where MODE is the octal representation of the mode. Note that this
; does not overwrite the process's umask.
; http://php.net/session.save-path
;session.save_path = "/tmp"

; Whether to use cookies.
; http://php.net/session.use-cookies
session.use_cookies = 1

; http://php.net/session.cookie-secure
;session.cookie_secure =

; This option forces PHP to fetch and use a cookie for storing and maintaining
; the session id. We encourage this operation as it's very helpful in combating
; session hijacking when not specifying and managing your own session id. It is
; not the end all be all of session hijacking defense, but it's a good start.
; http://php.net/session.use-only-cookies
session.use_only_cookies = 1

; Name of the session (used as cookie name).
; http://php.net/session.name
session.name = PHPSESSID

; Initialize session on request startup.
; http://php.net/session.auto-start
session.auto_start = 0

; Lifetime in seconds of cookie or, if 0, until browser is restarted.
; http://php.net/session.cookie-lifetime
session.cookie_lifetime = 0
```

Cheers

Comment: My PHP installation is on C:\PHP and my php.ini is in C:/windows

Comment: just because you've got the .dll listed in the .ini file doesn't mean it's actually locatable/loadable. there can also be MULTIPLE .ini files in use, and you're modifying the wrong one.

Comment: did you restart the server/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Be sure to appropriately set the extension_dir directive.

Make sure that the `.dll` is in your extension folder. Then, try defining `extension_dir`.

```
; Directory in which the loadable extensions (modules) reside.
; http://php.net/extension-dir
; extension_dir = "./"
; On windows:
; extension_dir = "ext"
```

Comment: you need to set your extension_dir as a full path in windows, just "ext" on its own wont do it

Comment: Cheers, I missed that line. I guess I got a bit blind.